# Could anyone please help with defining a vector function of tons of variables?

Tags: programming, procedural-programming, subscript, code

Could anyone please help with effectively defining a vector-valued function of tons of variables so that

```
f[w1_, w2_, ..., w5000_] := {{w1^5000}, {w2^4999}, ...,{w5000^1}}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: `f = ArrayReshape[#, {Length[#], 1}] &`? (Usage: `f[w]` where `w  = {w1, w2,...}`)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thank you for your comment, but how does that work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

"13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"

Clear["Global`*"]
```

For a variable number of arguments

```
f[args__] := List /@ {args};

vars = Array[w, 10];

f @@ vars

(* {{w[1]}, {w[2]}, {w[3]}, {w[4]}, {w[5]}, {w[6]}, {w[7]}, {w[8]}, 
    {w[9]}, {w[10]}} *)
```

**EDIT:** For the revised question

```
Clear[f]

f[args__] := List /@ ({args}^Range[Length[{args}], 1, -1])

f @@ vars

(* {{w[1]^10}, {w[2]^9}, {w[3]^8}, {w[4]^7}, {w[5]^6}, {w[6]^5}, 
   {w[7]^4}, {w[8]^3}, {w[9]^2}, {w[10]}} *)
```

If there must be 5000 arguments then

```
Clear[f]

f[args__ /; Length[{args}] == 5000] := List /@ {args}

vars = Array[w, 5000];

(f @@ vars) // Short
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For the revised question

```
Clear[f]

f[args__ /; Length[{args}] == 5000] := 
 List /@ ({args}^Range[5000, 1, -1])

(f @@ vars) // Short[#, 3] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: But how to connect the "vars" with the "args"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `args` is just the name of a pattern used in the definition of `f` to represent a sequence of arguments. When you `Apply` `f` to a `List` of arguments the `Sequence` inside that `List` matches the pattern for `args`. i.e., `f @@ {x1, x2, x3, ...}` becomes `f[x1, x2, x3, ...]`, that is, the `Head` `f` replaces the `Head` `List`. You could also accomplish this with `{x1, x2, x3, ...}` /. List -> f`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to define your vector using Array:

```
n = 5; wVec = Array[w, n];
```

To get the function you want, take:

```
wVec^Range[n, 1, -1]
```

So for n=5, you get

```
{w[1]^5, w[2]^4, w[3]^3, w[4]^2, w[5]}
```

Change n to 5000 and you'll have a much larger expression.